# Need an SQL query with multiple, dynamic "WHERE" condition

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

I need a query that would show all the posts of the connected user and his friends, in the context of a social netowork.

Users table headers:
ID, account_name, password, name, birthdate, description

Posts table headers:
ID, user_ID, text, date

Friends table headers:
ID_user_1, ID_user_2

Current query:

```
select p.ID, p.users_ID, p.text, p.date, u.ID, u.name
from post p
inner join users u
on p.users_ID = u.ID
where p.users_ID = 1 or p.users_ID=(
   select users_ID_2 from friends
   where users_ID_1 = 1)
order by date
```

Note: The current users_ID (1) will be a variable inserted via PHP.

My problem is that my subquery returns multiple rows, namely the ID of each of the connected user's friends.

Comment: Do `p.users_ID IN (...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
select p.ID, p.users_ID, p.text, p.date, u.ID, u.name
from post p
inner join users u
on p.users_ID = u.ID
where p.users_ID = 1 
   or p.users_ID IN 
    (select users_ID_2 from friends
      where users_ID_1 = 1)
order by date
```